# How to use multiple callables?

Tags: java, multithreading, file, callable

I have a text file with a list of 5000 names and whether the name is Male("MO") or Female only ("FO") or Male and Female("MF") formatted like so.

FO ABBY

MO ABDUL

MO ABE

MO ABEL

FO ABIGAIL

I want to use a callable then return how many "FO", "MO" and "MF" there are in the file and store the return values in a future list then output them to the screen.

I am expecting following output :

MF - 331

MO - 0

FO - 3944

How do I call multiple callables that computes at the same time. I'm not getting anything for the "FO" and the majority of the names are "FO".

Expected results should be distributed something like this.

MF - 500

MO - 1500

FO - 3000

I am new to multi-threading so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I would appreciate it if you could point me in the right direction

```
  public class ParsingTextFile {
  /**Main method
 * @throws InterruptedException 
 * @throws ExecutionException */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    // Declare file reader and writer streams

      String code = null ;


      List<Callable<Integer>> callables = Arrays.asList(
                callable("MF",ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 5 + 1)),
                callable("MO",ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 5 + 1)),
                callable("FO",ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 5 + 1))
                );
      // Process a record

      ExecutorService exe = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
      List<Future<Integer>> arr = exe.invokeAll(callables);


      for (Future<Integer> s : arr) { 
            System.out.println(s.get());
        }


      exe.shutdownNow();

    }




  static Callable<Integer> callable(String result, long sleepSeconds) {
        return () -> {

            int count = 0;

            FileReader frs = null;
            FileWriter fws = null;

            // Declare streamTokenizer
            StreamTokenizer in = null;

            // Declare a print stream
            PrintWriter out = null;

            try     {
                  // Create file input and output streams
                  frs = new FileReader("census.txt");


                  // Create a stream tokenizer wrapping file input stream
                  in = new StreamTokenizer(frs);



                  // Read first token
                  in.nextToken();



            while (in.ttype != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF)     {
                // Get student name

                if (in.ttype == StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD)
                {
                  String val = in.sval;

                    if (val.equals("MF") && result == "MF")
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    else if(val.equals("MO") && result == "M0")
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    else if(val.equals("FO") && result == "FO")
                    {
                        count++;
                    }

                }

                else
                  System.out.println("Bad file format");



                in.nextToken();
              }
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException ex)   {
              System.out.println("File not found: census.text");
            }
            catch (IOException ex)   {
              System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
            finally   {
              try     {

                if (frs != null) frs.close();
                if (fws != null) fws.close();
              }
              catch (IOException ex)  {
                System.out.println(ex);
              }
            }

        return count;

        };

  }
```

Comment: `result == "M0"`? I thought it was `MO`. Also, use `equals` to compare `String`s.

Comment: Wow, that was the problem! 0 instead of O. I ran it there and the results added up exactly to how much records there are in the file.

Comment: btw: Consider using the [try-resource statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).